# Editing my answer that has been upvoted, accepted and has bounty paid

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

The question I'm talking about is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851632/issues-with-newline-character-while-using-ansi-term-in-emacs/37038271)

My answer is short enough to quote:

> You need to `stty onlcr` in your script.
>
> I will leave the forensics of exactly where this is being unset in the tcsh environment as a exercise for the questioner ;)

Obviously this answer fails on a number of counts:

- It fails to say *why* the solution fixes the problem
- It fails to give even basic advice on how to investigate the root cause of the problem.
- Its tone is perhaps a little flippant and informal

In my defense - debugging the problem required a sitdown in chat with the questioner but the time difference meant that Wednesday evening after work for him was early AM Thursday morning for me, so once it was solved I was anxious to get to bed before I had to get up again.

My Concern:
There are three parties involved here. The SO community who have already up-voted the answer, the questioner who accepted it and paid from his own reputation, and me - I consider the answer sub-standard and would like to improve it.

So my question to meta is: Do we all have equal rights here?
Is it ok to edit the answer with the *intention* of improving it and then wait for the community and the questioner to weigh in with their opinions of the edit. What is the accepted etiquette?

I edited my answer. Feel free to weigh in with your thoughts.

Comment: "It fails to say why the solution fixes the problem" Just want to add that while this is nice to have, often it's not needed to understand why a solution fixes a problem. If users upvoted the question without an explanation they will surely upvote it even more if there is one. "Its tone is perhaps a little flippant and informal" this can and should always be edited by anyone on SO including the original author.

Comment: Yes, I'd say in the majority of cases the solution is its own explanation and requires no further exposition. We are all smart people here right? stty options can be a little arcane though so I thought it best in this particular case.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's got your name on it. All else being equal, you get first crack at saying what goes and what doesn't. Now, if you abuse that we might run into problems, but... As long as you're setting out to *improve* on your existing work, I see no conflict here.

Comment: All is right with the world then. As for my name, well that was an embarrassing mishap while editing my profile which (apparently) I can't fix for a month :(  I'm curious what you mean by abuse though?

Comment: @user6170930 If you edit the post to remove any semblance of the answer and just start swearing at the OP and hurling personal insults, that would be an abusive edit, and be rolled back to the original content regardless of your intention for the answer to say otherwise.

Comment: lol, and rightly so. But given the nature and intent of my question here I think any reasonable person would rate the probability of that happening as extremely low - don't you think?

Comment: I suppose I'm a little miffed at being scolded for something I would never do in a month of sundays...getting over it now...no wait...might take a little longer, but I'll get there ;)

Comment: I'm not scolding you, @user. I'm saying overt abuse would be the only situation where such an edit would be an issue. IOW, you're not likely to encounter problems.

Comment: Understood. Its important for the completeness of your answer. In my part of the world we might say 'if one were' in place of 'if you' in that situation. English is a tricky business.

Comment: Indeed it is. One might use similar phrasing here, if one wishes to appear pretentious... Connotations are hard to gauge in a global community!

Comment: Agreed. We [The Royal We] will endeavour to be less of that (though one shouldn't hold ones breath) and perhaps a little less sensitive to boot.

Comment: After this amusing little conversation yesterday I just couldn't resist using the phrase "one might say" in my updated answer. I hope I'll be forgiven <3

Comment: We can always revert the edit if it's horrible!

Answer (score 31):

If you only want to *improve* your answer, for example add more information, without changing the core of the answer, it's OK to edit it.

However, if you want to *change* your answer (for instance because you realized that you were wrong), after it has been accepted and awarded a bounty, I would recommend you posting a new answer instead. If the OP decides that your second answer is better, they can change the accepted answer to this. This also lets the community express their opinion on the quality of your second answer by voting.

Comment: If you have determined an answer of yours to be incorrect, please delete it. If it's accepted, ask the OP or flag for a mod to un-accept it. There's already enough wrong content on the web, don't add to that. It is not the poster's problem that the voters don't know what they're doing.

Comment: @CodeCaster Good point, but I think that you should delete your answer only if it's harmful. If it's only wrong, adding a disclaimer on the top that you determined it to be incorrect is enough.

Comment: @CodeCaster moderators can't unaccept answers...

Answer (score -1):

There is always another party, 1000 times bigger than all these three: the site visitors coming from search sites.

- The OP may abandon their question, Stack Overflow and programming the next day they ask.
- The community is in the past: the language may change; your knowledge may grow; the new bugs can be discovered. Why clutch to the ancient achievements? Why let them to hinder the knowledge sharing?
- Your interest is what? For whom you are editing your answer? Is it really for the OP who accepted your answer long time ago?

Answer yourself these questions and you'll know the answer to the OP.

A hint: imagine Wikipedia editors thinking like you.

Comment: That party, or at least the subset of them that will offer me work at some point, might be part of my motivation for keeping the standards of my answers as high as possible. They do not have any rights in this situation so I omitted them from my query. I would like to think however - though I have no experience its inner workings - that Wikipedia could only benefit from the care I have taken here to engage with members of long standing before making significant changes to my contribution.

Answer (score -22):

One thing you could do would be to leave the original text intact, then add an EDIT marker, like this:

## EDIT

and then add your new text after that. In this way the original accepted answer is still visible, but you get can update it to read as you wish.

Comment: If you’re not changing the overall core part of the answer, adding a big “EDIT” that separates two parts of your answer that effectively say the same, is just a useless thing to do. If you just want to expand on your existing content, do that without telling everybody that you did. That improves the quality of the answer and avoids confusing those who come later and never got to see the original version.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that giant ***EDIT*** notices are discouraged, because the point of Stack Overflow is to provide a clean, professional-looking experience, and giant ***EDIT*** notes disrupt that.

Comment: I usually edit out the edit notices - they provide a tiny amount of value for a short period of time, and then they're just massively annoying and borderline incoherent.